# virtual folder is invisible in the CFileDialog in windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, registry, shell-extensions, shell-namespace-extension

-------------------------update 5th-------------------------------

```
            if (fIsFolder)
            {
                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FOLDER;
            }
            else
            {
                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_SYSTEM;

                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FILESYSTEM;
            }

            if (nLevel < g_nMaxLevel)
            {
                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_HASSUBFOLDER;

                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR;
            }
```

Now this one works normally in application A, stackoverflow image upload file dialog and in regular folder explorer.

-----------------------------------------------------update 4th-----------------------------------------------------------
After add `dwAttribs |= SFGAO_SYSTEM;` , now at least for application A, it works as expected in the file dialog. But the folder is still not clickable in the regular folder dialog or for `CWFileDialog`.

```
            if (fIsFolder)
            {
                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FOLDER;

                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FILESYSTEM;

                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR;
            }
            else
            {
                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_SYSTEM;// this line of code works better

                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FILESYSTEM;
            }
```

-----------------------------------update third-----------------------------------------
This is the code in the virtual folder's ISHellFolder:

After I edit the following code to add `dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FILESYSTEM;`, the folder cannot be browsed when I double click it in the folder view. But it can be opened by left clicking it in the tree view.

```
 HRESULT CFolderViewImplFolder::GetAttributesOf(UINT cidl, PCUITEMID_CHILD_ARRAY apidl, ULONG *rgfInOut)
{
// If SFGAO_FILESYSTEM is returned, GetDisplayNameOf(SHGDN_FORPARSING) on that item MUST
// return a filesystem path.
HRESULT hr = E_INVALIDARG;

DWORD dwAttribs = 0;

dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FILESYSTEM;

if (1 == cidl)
{
    int nLevel = 0;
    hr = _GetLevel(apidl[0], &nLevel);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        BOOL fIsFolder = FALSE;
        hr = _GetFolderness(apidl[0], &fIsFolder);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            
            if (fIsFolder)
            {
                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FOLDER;
            }
            if (nLevel < g_nMaxLevel)
            {
                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_HASSUBFOLDER;
            }
  
        }
    }
}

*rgfInOut &= dwAttribs;

return hr;
}`
```

Or

```
DWORD dwAttribs = 0;

if (1 == cidl)
{
    int nLevel = 0;
    hr = _GetLevel(apidl[0], &nLevel);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        BOOL fIsFolder = FALSE;
        hr = _GetFolderness(apidl[0], &fIsFolder);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            
            if (fIsFolder)
            {
                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FOLDER;

                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FILESYSTEM;

                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR;
            }
            else
            {
                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_SYSTEM;
            }

            if (nLevel < g_nMaxLevel)
            {
                dwAttribs |= SFGAO_HASSUBFOLDER;
            }
        }
    }
 }

*rgfInOut &= dwAttribs;
```

Other code are the same as in `update 2nd`.
The weird stuff is, after I edit these code, application A which uses `CFileDialog` normally( not wrapping it, not set `m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode` to true) can display all virtual folder normally as I expected.
But in all other applications( including the one uses `CWFileDilao` which set `m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode` to true is still cannot view the virtual folder.

---------------------------------------update 2nd-------------------------

I code a simple class which derives from CFileDialog:

```
class CWFileDlg : public CFileDialog
{
public:
CWFileDlg(BOOL bOpenFileDialog, // TRUE for FileOpen, FALSE for FileSaveAs
    LPCTSTR lpszDefExt = NULL,
    LPCTSTR lpszFileName = NULL,
    DWORD dwFlags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT,
    LPCTSTR lpszFilter = NULL,
    CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL,
    DWORD dwSize = 0,
    BOOL bVistaStyle = TRUE);

~CWFileDlg();
};

CWFileDlg::CWFileDlg(BOOL bOpenFileDialog, // TRUE for FileOpen, FALSE for FileSaveAs
                    LPCTSTR lpszDefExt,
                    LPCTSTR lpszFileName,
                    DWORD dwFlags,
                    LPCTSTR lpszFilter,
                    CWnd* pParentWnd,
                    DWORD dwSize,
                    BOOL bVistaStyle) : CFileDialog(bOpenFileDialog, lpszDefExt, lpszFileName, dwFlags, lpszFilter, pParentWnd, dwSize, bVistaStyle)
{
    m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode = TRUE;
}

CWFileDlg::~CWFileDlg()
{

}
```

Then I call it like:

```
CWFileDlg dlg(TRUE, NULL, 0, OFN_SHAREAWARE | OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, L"all(*.*)|*.*||", this);

BOOL IsPickNonFileSysFoldersMode = dlg.IsPickNonFileSysFoldersMode();
//the value it gets is 1, which is TRUE

INT_PTR result = dlg.DoModal();
```

But in the pop up dialog, virtual folder is stil invisible. Tree view for it is also invisible.
------------------------------------------updates----------------------------

```
protected:

BOOL m_bVistaStyle;
BOOL m_bPickFoldersMode;
BOOL m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode;
DWORD m_dwCookie;
void* m_pIFileDialog;
void* m_pIFileDialogCustomize;
```

The `m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode` is not a public type. How could I set it to TRUE ?

```
Error   1   error C2248: 'CFileDialog::m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'CFileDialog'   c:\users\liyuan.liu\documents\dp-dll\testvirtualfolder\browser2\browser2\browser2dlg.cpp    166 1   browser2
```

---

By using Microsoft windows sample code, I installed a virtual folder on windows 7 by using shell namespace extension.
The following screenshot is using regular folder browser to open it:
[image]

Then I wrote a project which can create a file dialog:

```
CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, NULL, 0, OFN_SHAREAWARE | OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, L"all(*.*)|*.*||", this);
INT_PTR result = dlg.DoModal();
```

However, in the file browser, the virtual folder is invisible:

[image]

But! When I was trying to upload the screenshot to StackOverflow ( the web browser I am using is chrome), the file dialog which is used to select file can display the tree view ( only the tree view) of the virtual folder:
[image]

By googling, it seems that the CFileDialog cannot support to display the virtual folder since it doesn't actually exist in the system. Any solutions to solve that?
I also tried with

```
bi.pidlRoot = pidlVirtual;
bi.ulFlags = BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS | BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS | BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES | BIF_BROWSEFILEJUNCTIONS;
LPITEMIDLIST pidl = SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);
```

Also doesn't work.

Comment: Did you create and register both 32bit and 64bit NSE?

Comment: `CFileDialog` wraps `IFileDialog` by default in Visual Studio 2008 and later. `IFileDialog` definitely supports virtual folders and SNEs (that's its big improvement over the older `Get(Open|Save)FileName()` APIs). What version of Visual Studio are you using? Maybe `CFileDialog` in your version is using the older filesystem-only APIs. Have you tried using `IFileDialog` directly?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what the file dialog shows is function of the app that opens it. Starting with Vista, it's the `IFileDialog` interface which is used, and it defines a set of options through the [IFileDialog::SetOptions method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761832.aspx).

The `FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM` flag ensures that returned items are file system items (SFGAO_FILESYSTEM), and that depends on how you wrote your extension. SFGAO_FILESYSTEM should ring a bell, it's one of the flags the [IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775068.aspx) can return. If what you do is really virtual (ie: if you don't return this flag), they won't be shown when IFileDialog is configured like this.

If you test your extension with different apps (notepad, word, excel, browsers, etc.), you'll see that you see it sometimes, and sometimes you don't.

Spelunking into MFC's code (`dlgfile.cpp`), you will find this:

```
    // We only expect and handle file system paths (for compatibility with GetOpenFileName functionality), so set the
    // "force file system" flag which enables GetOpenFileName-like download behavior for non file system paths, unless
    // the m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode is set to allow picking non-file system folders (like libraries in Windows 7).
    dwFlags |= FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM;
    if (m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode)
    {
        dwFlags &= ~FOS_FORCEFILESYSTEM;
    }
```

So, you need to set `m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode` to TRUE for CFileDialog to show your extension. in MFC you must derive from CFileDialog since this member is protected (BTW this is a stupid MFC design decision), for example::

```
class MyFileDialog : public CFileDialog
{
public:
    MyFileDialog(LPCTSTR lpszDefExt = NULL, LPCTSTR lpszFileName = NULL, DWORD dwFlags = OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, LPCTSTR lpszFilter = NULL, CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL);
};

MyFileDialog::MyFileDialog(LPCTSTR lpszDefExt, LPCTSTR lpszFileName, DWORD dwFlags, LPCTSTR lpszFilter, CWnd* pParentWnd) : CFileDialog(TRUE, lpszDefExt, lpszFileName, dwFlags, lpszFilter, pParentWnd)
{
    m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode = TRUE;
}
```

Last thing to remember: make sure your virtual folder (namespace extension, etc.) is registered with the same bitness (x86 vs x64) as the app using the CFileDialog.

But it won't fix other apps you don't own that use this flag...

Comment: How could I set m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode to TRUE for CFileDialog ? It seems that this variable is inaccessible out of CFileDialog. When I am checking for the definition of CFileDialog, it is  class CFileDialog : public CCommonDialog

Comment: The member is protected, so you'll have to derive from CFileDialog and set the value to TRUE in the constructor.

Comment: I wrap it, and set the flag to TRUE, but it still invisible. Please see my updates.

Comment: What do you return for the root folder in GetAttributesOf?

Comment: I add the SFGAO_FILESYSTEM, please check  my update in the 3rd one

Comment: But after I add SFGAO_FILESYSTEM, from another application( let's call it A), A's file dialog can display the content of the virtual folder. The weird stuff is, in application A, it uses CFileDialog normally(not wrap it, not set m_bPickNonFileSysFoldersMode to TRUE). A is our company's application which I can see its code.